# setInterval executes only once

Tags: javascript, setinterval, anonymous-function

I'm having trouble with a setInterval function. It executes, but only once.

```
function show(el){
    el.style.opacity = 0;
    el.style.display = "block";
    showingInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
            el.style.opacity += 0.001;
            if(el.style.opacity == 1) {
                alert("done");
                clearInterval(showingInterval);
            }
        }, 1);
}
```

The function `show(el)` is not the problem. It changes opacity to `0` and display to `"block"` just fine. The interval function runs one time changing the opacity of the element to `0.0001`. It stays at that state and doesn't change any more, though.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: convert your `el.style.opacity` to a float with `parseFloat()` first.

Comment: @Deryck that did the trick. See jAndy's answer as well

Comment: glad to hear it worked out.  let us know if you run into more trouble down the road :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem, `Element.node.style` is not reliable. To check for current states and values, always use `window.getComputedStyle( Node )`.

Second problem, css properties are represented in *Strings*, you cannot operate with math operators like `+=`.

```
el.style.opacity = parseFloat( getComputedStyle( el ).opacity ) + 0.001;
```

Comment: Didn't know about `window.getComputedStyle(node)`. I will read up on that for certain.
Changing it like you suggested worked! Problem was indeed the missing `parseFloat()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that [`+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) in your case is not a math sum operation but string concatenation. This happens because unary `+` operator performs string concatenation if at least one of the operands is a string type. Values of the `DOMElement.style` properties are always strings, so in your case incremented opacity values looks like this:

```
"0" + 0.001 // => "00.001"
```

When you apply this value as the new `opacity`, browser, since it's invalid format, sets it to "0" again.

All you need to to is to cast `el.style.opacity` to Number type. For example with `Number` function:

```
el.style.opacity = Number(el.style.opacity) + 0.01;
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gvg31gd1/

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution need to declare just one variable

your code is not icreamenet opacity value thats why i wasnt work

```
var opacity = 0;
function show(el){
el.style.opacity = 0;
el.style.display = "block";
showingInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
       opacity = opacity + 0.001;
        el.style.opacity = opacity;
        document.write(opacity)
        if(el.style.opacity == 1) {
            alert("done");
            clearInterval(showingInterval);
        }
    }, 1);
```

}